# Why can't I open this specific executable with my python script and is there a workaround?

Tags: python, c#

I am trying to open an executable in my python script like so:

```
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.call('C:\\[...]\\DarkSouls3EnemyRandomizer\\pooremma.exe')
    process.wait()
```

and i get an error window which says:

```
> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quick, the application closes immediately.

and this debug info:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: files\picture\runundead.png
   bei System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   bei pooremma.Randomizer.Randomizer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

and on clicking continue the executable starts opening a window with all .jpg's missing and upon clicking
a button i get the same error again

after that i tried executing it via console and it failed in the same fashion
so i wanted to now if there is a workaround to simulate the same conditions like for double clicking the executable in the windows explorer window

thanks for everyone who powered through this wall of text ;)

Comment: Try changing the CWD to ...\\DarkSouls3EnemyRandomizer then try running your exe from there.

Comment: Perhaps your executable needs to start in the right directory. Does it work when you run it from the command line if you start it in the same directory as your python script? Have you tried to "chdir()" to the exe's directory before executing it?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel
tried just now but didnt work

Comment: changing current working directory works for console but my python script does not do it

Comment: nvm, put a print after ```os.chdir('path)``` and it suddenly worked. thanks a bunch

Comment: if it works from the console then you should be able to do the same from the python script. subprocess.call has a [cwd parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments i found out that changing the current working directory to the path of the executable helped but only after i put a `print(os.getcwd)` behind it